# Why is instantiating a lot of prefabs made with ProBuilder so slow?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making an FPS game in unity. So far I'm working on a procedurally generated map/arena. This means a lot of instantiated prefabs at the start of the game.

Each prefab is a prototype of a building with (on average 5-10) gameobjects made in Probuilder - mostly just planes.

However, I have run into a problem - the instantiations are very slow. I tried to run the game in a profiler and it seems like the gameobjects made with probuilder run some kind of their logic on awake. And this logic takes up too much time.

What is the culprit in the slow instantiations? What precautions should i take to make it faster?

I'm using unity 2020.3.43f1 and probuilder 4.5.2, if that matters (I picked up this project again after not working on it for about an year and didn't care about updating packages).

Here is a screenshot from profiler:

[image: screenshot from profiler]